# Exporting and re-using Armature

Tags: rigging, armature, export

I want to re-use an armature and the animations on it. Can I just export it as FBX, then import on another project so I can have the same animation on a different mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you export an armature and its animation as an fbx file format, you will have to re-parent the armature to the new mesh, and set up all of the weight painting, but you can keep the animation and the armature structure, if that is what you want to do. Select the armature, and export it as an fbx. Then import it into the new file.

Comment: My second mesh is a different mesh so I am thinking I need to re-parent and re-weight it. But that's the only way I know, is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure About the Animation but you can simply open a second Blender and copy Paste from one to another for the Armature.

Comment: Not on a Mac OS system.